# How can I overlay a html page on an one page design?

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently coding a one page design - one page with all the content on the homepage - where I have different links to different external content pages, like `single.html`.
Where I am searching for his how I can overlay that single page over the index.html, so the smooth navigation will continue work and you will stand at the last position where the user was, for example `portfolio`.

On the internet I read that you can load content with jQuery’s function `load`, but this seems not to work for me.

The code looks like the following:

```
$("#buttonContact").click(function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({url:"contact.html",success:function(result){
         $("body").html(result);
       }});

});
```

Perhaps this snippet of code doesn’t work for me. 
Simply explanation of the code is, that when the user is clicking on the button with the id of `buttonContact`, `contact.html` should be loaded as a overlay on the homepage. Should I markup the single page - `single.html` the same as the index, with all the `head` stuff etc or should I remove some snippets of code out of that page?

On [www.dangblast.com](http://www.dangblast.com) you will see a working example of what I exactly means. Click on a thumbnail and the content will overlay the whole homepage.

Comment: This is usually done with javascript and jquery to switch out the contents of a page dynamically. Instead of a lot of html pages you will have a ton o javascript to do the exact same thing and basically dynamically write out the html.

Comment: Do you mean single ("long page") designs, or simply a single page that swaps out content when you click a link without the page refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTML. Everything you might put on multiple pages, put on a single page. Simple as that.

So if you have a menubar with links to different pages:

```
<a href='home'>Home</a> <a href="contact">Contact</a>...
```

... use page anchors instead, like:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a> <a href="#contact">Contact</a>...
```

(notice the only difference is the hash tags (#) in the `href` attribute.)

On each section of your page, simple add an `id` attribute to the headers or sectioning elements:

```
<h2 id="home">Hello, World!</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

<h2 id="contact">Give us a call</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

or

```
<section id="home">
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</section>

<section id="contact">
    <h1>Give us a call</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</section>
```

Do a Google search for "single page design" and you'll find lots of great implementation tips.